# CMake custom command always executes

Tags: cmake

In my CMakeLists.txt, I define a custom target and command:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/input.csv
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/output1.csv
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/output2.csv
    COMMAND python3 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tests/genVectors.py)

add_custom_target(TEST_VECTORS
    DEPENDS
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/input.csv
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/output1.csv
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/output2.csv)

add_executable(VectorTest tests/VectorTest.cpp)
add_dependencies(VectorTest TEST_VECTORS)
```

It always generates new CSV files even though the files exist. I only need to generate the vectors (with genVectors.py python file) if they do not exist. Is that something wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 3):

The [`OUTPUT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#generating-files) option of `add_custom_command` does not guarantee that the generated files are placed here; it just tells CMake that the generated files are **expected** to be placed there. It is likely that your python script is generating files at a relative path, so they are just being placed somewhere in your CMake *binary* directory (your build folder). So while your files may be generated correctly, your custom target doesn't see them because it is looking in `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`. Thus, the custom target will always trigger the custom command to re-run.

CMake runs `add_custom_command` from the `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` by default, but you can change it to run from `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` by adding the `WORKING_DIRECTORY` option. This way, the generated files will be placed at the *expected* location, and achieve your desired behavior. Try something like this:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/input.csv
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/output1.csv
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/output2.csv
    COMMAND python3 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tests/genVectors.py
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_custom_target(TEST_VECTORS
    DEPENDS
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/input.csv
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/output1.csv
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/output2.csv)

add_executable(VectorTest tests/VectorTest.cpp)
add_dependencies(VectorTest TEST_VECTORS)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to generate your file at time of configuration(i.e. while calling `cmake`). By this way it will created only once.

You can remove `add_custom_command` and use `execute_process` to create your files.