# CMake add_custom_command runs everytime

Tags: cmake

I am using a custom command for generating C++ Lexers and Parsers from ANTLR4 grammars. Right now I have the following:

```
set(MY_PARSER_INC
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Headers/MyParser/MyLexer.h
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Headers/MyParser/MyParser.h
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Headers/MyParser/MyParserBaseVisitor.h
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Headers/MyParser/MyParserVisitor.h
)
set(MY_PARSER_SRC
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Sources/MyParser/MyLexer.cpp
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Sources/MyParser/MyParser.cpp
)
add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT ${MY_PARSER_INC} ${MY_PARSER_SRC}
        DEPENDS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Grammars/MyGrammar.g4
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Headers/MyParser/
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Sources/MyParser/
        COMMAND java -cp "${ANTLR_CLASSPATH}" "org.antlr.v4.Tool" -Dlanguage=Cpp -visitor -no-listener -package MY::NESTED::NAMESPACE -encoding iso-8859-1 -o ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Sources/MyParser/ ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Grammars/MyGrammar.g4
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Sources/MyParser/*.h ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Headers/MyParser/
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove -f ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Sources/MyParser/*.h
        COMMENT "generating sources for My Parser"
)
```

and then I use the output files in my `add_library` command to maintain the dependency.

This does exactly what I expect it to do. It creates the lexers and parsers correctly. It maintains the dependency between those sources and the target library also correctly. Only one problem: It runs every time! Even when the grammar file has not been modified (I checked the file date on the grammar and generated lexers/parsers to be sure)! I have seen some similar questions online but still can't figure out why this is happening.

Any clue?!

### EDIT1:

Adding more info, since it may still be unclear.
After the `add_custom_command` I have the following:

```
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Headers/MyParser/)

add_library(MyLibrary SHARED
        ${MY_PARSER_INC} ${MY_PARSER_SRC}
        other_files.hpp other_files.cpp)
```

which I assume creates a direct dependency between the generated source files and my target library.

Comment: The symptoms of some OUTPUT files to be **not regenerated** by the custom command. Actually, `*.h` doesn't work in `cmake -E copy` command, see [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html). As you know all files produced by antlr, you could just enumerate them for this command.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I don't really understand the first statement. However, the copy command works fine. The files are there, they get updated correctly if I update the grammar, and I do include them in other files, I'd definitely notice if the copy failed.

Comment: You may try to debug a reason of rebuilding the files by youself. E.g if you use `make` utility to build the project, then pass `-d` [option](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html) to it.

Comment: Have you made a custom target?

Comment: As pointed out `cmake -E copy` doesn't support wildcards and `cmake -E remove` is deprecated. I'm going to guess that your script doesn't complete correctly and fails to update the timestamp file that some generators use when tracking custom commands.  That is the probably the dependency that is out of whack and causes the reruns you are seeing. But without details of the generator and tools being used I can't say for sure.

Comment: OK, retrying again with a workaround for `copy`.

Comment: I tried it, it works. Somehow the copy was workign before (I removed the files, reran and they respawned!) but I guess they must have screwed up the timestamp as you said.

Comment: It is a relatively old post, but this answer may help resolve the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58995789/17658327

Answer (score 0):

Here's my guess.

You need to make a custom target.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html?highlight=custom_target

```
add_custom_target(custom_target_create_parser_code DEPENDS
  ${MY_PARSER_INC} ${MY_PARSER_SRC}
)
```

This will make a target that depends on the custom command you wrote.

Now cmake has something to attach your command to.

Now you need to add the dependency to your static library you mentioned.
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html

```
add_dependency(your_static_library custom_target_create_parser_code)
```

Now cmake shouldn't re-run your custom command code everytime.

EDIT BTW:

Craig Scott's book actually has a subchapter devoted to this topic:

https://crascit.com/professional-cmake/

Chapter 18 Custom Targets

Chapter 18.3 Commands That Generate Files

EDIT #2:

If all else fails try the official cmake discourse:
https://discourse.cmake.org/

Your question is well formed and cmake developers look their for questions.
So you should get an answer.

Comment: But how is that different from including the generated sources and headers to the add_library line of my shared lib?

Comment: My understanding is the target create the actual dependency chain, that will check for timestamps. I think I'm right but it's also late so I could be wrong, hard to say without seeing you whole project. But I also have generated files in our project and basically this is what we do.

Comment: Giving a try to your suggestion now, will come back with the results

Comment: Unfortunately your suggestion didn't change anything, I'll take a look at that link though.

Comment: Sorry to bother could you try 1 more time changing the dependency?

Comment: Don't be sorry, this is supposed to be helping me :) However, I don't think creating a dependency with the grammar source is going to solve anything, since the problem is the dependency between the generated sources and the target library.

Going to try though.

Comment: You are not required to use `add_custom_target()` when using `add_custom_command()`.  But there are certain conditions where using `add_custom_target()` is preferred.  For instance when the `add_custom_command()` generates output to be used in multiple targets.

Comment: fdk1342 yeah you are probably right, custom commands are my weakest point of knowledge for cmake, that being said I looked at my custom command and the logic I had before was correct (at least with respect to my project). So I'm not really sure what the problem is.